# Exists function in XSL When Statement

Tags: xslt

I am using an XSL when clause to transform one XML file to another XML file.  I need to use something like an "exists" function in my when test.

Here's an example source XML:

```
<People>
    <Person personid="1" location="US" fullname="John Doe"/>
    <Person personid="2" location="US" fullname="Jane Doe"/>
</People>
<Nicknames>
    <Nickname personid="1" nname="Johnny D"/>
</Nicknames>
```

Here's my example XSL:

```
  <xsl:element name="HASNICKNAME">
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- If nickname exists in source XML, return true -->
      <xsl:when test="boolean exists function"
        <xsl:text>TRUE</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>FALSE</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:element>
```

Can someone help with the exists part?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a node exists using XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694480/check-if-a-node-exists-using-xslt)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767851/xpath-find-if-node-exists or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948878/xslt-detecting-if-a-node-exists or any of http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+xslt+exist+node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the variable `$personid` contains the `@personid` of the `Person` you are checking, then this only checks existence:

```
<xsl:when test="boolean(//Nickname[@personid=$personid]/@nname)">
```

For similar issues I normally prefer to check for a non-empty/non-whitespace value:

```
<xsl:when test="normalize-space(//Nickname[@personid=$personid]/@nname)!=''">
```

If you use a key like `<xsl:key name="nn" match="//Nickname" use="@personid"/>`, the following is also possible:

```
<xsl:when test="normalize-space(key('nn',$personid)/@nname)!=''">
```

The latter does not need the `$personid` variable but can directly work with the `@personid` of the `Person` you are checking…

Comment: Thanks mousio, I used the variable method with $personId and it worked perfectly.